# Registrar filas de un datatable con un checkbox JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Cómo podría hacer el procedimiento de una lista de asistencia que al momento de terminar de marcar los que están presentes presionar un boton y registrar los que estan presentes con su estado del `checkbox` (Marcado-> `True`, No Marcado-> `False`), desde ya gracias.

Estoy empenzando armarlo con este código en lo que es la parte de la vista (.xhtml)

```
<h:form id="frmAsistencia">
            <p:growl id="mensaje" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" life="3000"/>
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{asistenciaController.ListarJefAsistencia()}"/>
            <p:panel header="ASISTENCIA" style="font-size:13px;">
                <p style="margin-top:0px;"/>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group table-responsive box-table-class">
                            <p:dataTable id="tbAsistencia"
                                         value="#{asistenciaController.lstAsistencia}"
                                         var="asistencia"
                                         paginator="false"
                                         rowIndexVar="item"
                                         rows="20"
                                         rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50"
                                         emptyMessage="No existen empleados"
                                         tableStyleClass="table table-hover"
                                         style="font-family:Microsoft Sans Serif"
                                         rowKey="#{asistencia.c_c_usuario}">

                                <p:column style="font-family:Microsoft Sans Serif;width:70px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">Código</f:facet>
                                    <h:outputLabel value="#{asistencia.c_c_usuario}" style="font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column style="font-family:Microsoft Sans Serif;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">Usuario</f:facet>
                                    <h:outputLabel value="#{asistencia.c_t_usuario}" style="font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column style="width:50px;font-family:Microsoft Sans Serif;text-align:center;">
                                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{asistenciaController.asistencia.estado}">
                                        <p:ajax update=":frmAsistencia:mensaje" listener="#{asistenciaController.addMessage}"/>
                                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>

                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="form-group box-main-btn" style="margin-bottom:0px;height:29px">
                                            <p:commandButton value="Grabar"
                                                             style="font-family:Microsoft Sans Serif;height:28px;font-size:12px;width:100px;"
                                                             styleClass="btn btn-default"
                                                             action="#{asistenciaController.PruebaRegistroAsistencia}"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </f:facet>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
```

Este es el codigo del Controlador:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AsistenciaController extends GenericController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Asistencia asistencia;
    private List<Asistencia> lstAsistencia;
    public int totalAsistentes;
    private int totalInasistentes;
    private List<String> checkPersona = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<Asistencia> lstSeleccionAsistencia;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.setAsistencia(new Asistencia());
        this.setLstAsistencia(new ArrayList<Asistencia>());
    }

    public Asistencia getAsistencia() {
        return asistencia;
    }

    public void setAsistencia(Asistencia asistencia) {
        this.asistencia = asistencia;
    }

    public List<Asistencia> getLstAsistencia() {
        return lstAsistencia;
    }

    public void setLstAsistencia(List<Asistencia> lstAsistencia) {
        this.lstAsistencia = lstAsistencia;
    }

    public int getTotalAsistentes() {
        return totalAsistentes;
    }

    public void setTotalAsistentes(int totalAsistentes) {
        this.totalAsistentes = totalAsistentes;
    }

    public int getTotalInasistentes() {
        return totalInasistentes;
    }

    public void setTotalInasistentes(int totalInasistentes) {
        this.totalInasistentes = totalInasistentes;
    }

    public List<Asistencia> getLstSeleccionAsistencia() {
        return lstSeleccionAsistencia;
    }

    public void setLstSeleccionAsistencia(List<Asistencia> lstSeleccionAsistencia) {
        this.lstSeleccionAsistencia = lstSeleccionAsistencia;
    }

    public void ListarJefAsistencia() throws Exception {
        AsistenciaServiceImpl asistenciaServiceImpl = null;
        try {
            asistenciaServiceImpl = new AsistenciaServiceImpl();
            this.setLstAsistencia(asistenciaServiceImpl.ListarJefAsistencia());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            super.msggenError("Error", "Error al mostrar la asistencia: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void PruebaRegistroAsistencia() throws Exception {
        for(String it : checkPersona) {
            for(int i = 0; i < lstAsistencia.size(); i++) {
                if(it == lstAsistencia.get(i).getC_c_usuario()) {
                    System.out.print(it.indexOf(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkPersona(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        String[] check = (String[]) event.getNewValue();
        for(int i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
            checkPersona.add(check[i]);
        }
    }

    public void addMessage() {
        String summary = asistencia.isEstado() ? "Checked" : "Unchecked";
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(summary));
    }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Leandro, para poder entenderte mejor el problema que plantes edita la pregunta y agrega tu codigo

Comment: Hola @RaulCacacho he agregado los codigos que estoy integrando.

Comment: cuando dice jsf a que se refiere?

Comment: El xhtml o html

Comment: ahí esta publicado

Comment: En que metodo quieres poner la validación de las asistencias?

Comment: Gracias por el aporte @RaulCacacho, la idea es que al momento de grabar, se grabe toda la lista recorriendo los checkbox (Si esta seleccionado se graba como true si no esta seleccionado se graba como false y asi para cada usuario)

Comment: Te deje la respuesta ahi en la lista solo seria de setterarle true para cuando la guardes

Answer (score 1):

Para seleccionar con check en la tabla creas dos listas mas una es las que seleccionas, la otra se utiliza cuando tienes el paginador para que las filtre correctamente.

Las propiedades que agregue fueron

- `selection="#{asistenciaController.selectedAsistencia}"`
- `filteredValue="#{asistenciaController.AsistenciaFiltrada}"`
- `<p:column selectionMode="multiple" width="3%" />`

  Esta columna la puedes poner al principio o al final

**xhtml**

```
<p:dataTable id="tbAsistencia"
value="#{asistenciaController.lstAsistencia}"
var="asistencia" paginator="false"
rowIndexVar="item" rows="20"
rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50"
emptyMessage="No existen empleados"
ableStyleClass="table table-hover"
style="font-family:Microsoft Sans Serif"
selection="#{asistenciaController.selectedAsistencia}"
filteredValue="#{asistenciaController.AsistenciaFiltrada}"
rowKey="#{asistencia.c_c_usuario}">

<p:column selectionMode="multiple" width="3%" />

<p:column style="font-family:Microsoft Sans Serif;width:70px;">
<f:facet name="header">Código</f:facet>
<h:outputLabel value="#{asistencia.c_c_usuario}" style="font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;"/>
</p:column>
<p:column style="font-family:Microsoft Sans Serif;">
<f:facet name="header">Usuario</f:facet>
<h:outputLabel value="#{asistencia.c_t_usuario}" style="font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;"/>
 </p:column>
 <p:column style="width:50px;font-family:Microsoft Sans Serif;text-align:center;">
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{asistenciaController.asistencia.estado}">
  <p:ajax update=":frmAsistencia:mensaje" listener="#{asistenciaController.addMessage}"/>
  </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
  </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
```

En el **managedBean**

```
 public void PruebaRegistroAsistencia() throws Exception {
    for(String it : checkPersona) {
        for (Asistencia asis : selectedAsistencia) {
         .... //las condiciones que consideres necesarias
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < lstAsistencia.size(); i++) {
            if(it == lstAsistencia.get(i).getC_c_usuario()) {
                System.out.print(it.indexOf(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```